# Retrieving a specific class type element from base class vector in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

So I have a base class and a derived class:

```cpp
class BaseClass {
    public:
        virtual void print() { std::cout << "hi" << std::endl; }
        BaseClass() = default;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        void print() { std::cout << "bye" << std::endl; }
        DerivedClass() = default;

};
```

I also have a `std::vector<BaseClass*> list`.

I want to have a function that retrieves the first instance of a chosen class, similar to Unity3D engine's GetComponent function. This is how I tried to implement it:

```cpp
template <class T>
T* getInstance() {
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)list.size(); ++i) {
        if(typeid(list[i]) == typeid(T))
            return list[i];
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Can someone please explain to my what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention if I had any errors:

`Error  C2440   'return': cannot convert from '_Ty' to 'T *'` at line `return list[i];`.

Doesn't seem to have to do with the fact that I don't have any T parameter.

**Edit 2:**

Added a T parameter as a 'temporary' workaround
Code calling getInstance:

```cpp
int main() {
    getInstance<Derived>(Derived())->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What problem(s) did you face in your posted code?

Comment: What’s happening? How are you calling `getInstance`? Mismatch between `T` and `U*`, if I had to venture a guess.

Comment: Note that a function cannot be overloaded only by its return type. At least one of its parameters must have a different type. Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/

Comment: Are you sure that's the issue? The error I get is:
`'return': cannot convert from '_Ty' to 'T *'` , at line `return list[i];`

Comment: Please show the code calling the `getInstance()` function

Comment: added in the edit, though it's just a line of code

Comment: Presumably `list` is a list/vector defined like `list<T>`? In which case, it's saying it can't convert the element from type `T` to `T*`, which makes sense to me. You can return `&list[i]`

Comment: list is a BaseClass* vector